# Why won't my Acer batteries charge

Tags: laptop, battery, acer-aspire, charging

I have 2 Acer E5 575G laptops.  The battery in one died and I bought a replacement.  After installing the replacement the battery shows 39% available, not charging.  I contacted the seller who said that it may be a motherboard problem.  So I took the battery from the other laptop and installed it in the one with the new battery. It shows 100% not charging.  After that I put the 100% battery back into the original lalptop which was charging OK before I took it out, and it says 100% available, not charging.
I have tried a battery reset, uninstalled the battery drivers and used a different adapter on both laptops.  They still show 100% and 39% available, not charging.  I did a fresh install of Windows 10 on the laptop with the 39% problem and that didn't help.  Both laptops work when on the adapter.
 What have I missed?          Nothing that I have done works.

Comment: UPDATE:  This is solved!!  In my original post I wondered what I had missed doing.  In trying to save time in case the battery did not work, I tested the battery before I reassembled the laptop. The battery was detected but it woul not charge.  After reassembly I checked the battery again but it would not charge.         Here's what I missed....In order for the battery to charge the laptop must be completely reassembled and it must be on the charger for about 2 hours.  Even if it is fully charged.  After these two things, both laptops ran on battery power as normal.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

A battery is not charging when it's full, that's perfectly normal. Discharge it to, say, 75% and it should start charging (unless your laptop is configured to not charge over some threshold

The other one which is 39% full should be charging. Try it in the other laptop. If it's not charging, it's battery's fault.